# how to create and acces json object that created in the server through ajax success django

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, django-views

The  idea is: I want to call json object from ajax and return it's value.

I have something like this in my view :

> ```
>        if user is not None:
>             login(request, user)
>             link1 = "http://www.google.com"
>             link2 = "http://www.yahoo.com"
>             json = simplejson.dumps({"link1":link1, "link2":link2})   # I think problem is here
> return HttpResponse(json, mimetype="text/json")
> ```

and my JQuery:

```
function register_user() {
    $("#register-user").click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/registration/register_user/",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "text",
            data: {
                username : $("#id_username").val(),
                email : $("#id_email").val(),
                password : $("#id_password").val(),
                password2 : $("#id_password2").val(),
            },
            success: function(data) {
                if (data) {
                    alert(data.link1);  # this returns "undefined"
                }
                else {
                    alert("Error");
                }

            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: "How to do something like this in $.ajax  alert(data.link1) or alert(link1)"

Comment: you haven't assigned the value to link1 on client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your success function, try to do `parsed_data = $.parseJSON(data)`, then you can use `parsed_data.link1`.